# load method doesn't work when try to load new html into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem to load a new html (in a local folder) into a div when I try to program using jquery mobile. In the script function, it looks like the empty() works casuse the previous content in the maindiv will be cleaned. However, the new page was not loaded in the div. It stays purely white space. Please help. Thanks in advance. The jquery mobile version I used is jquery mobile 1.4.3. Thanks a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ABC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/customizedstyle.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#demo-page", function() {

            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
                if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #demo-page :not(INPUT):not(TEXTAREA) {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        /* Content styling. */
        dl { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; padding: 1em; }
        dt { font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; }
        dt span { font-size: .5em; color: #777; margin-left: .5em; }
        dd { font-size: 1.25em; margin: 1em 0 0; padding-bottom: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; }
        .back-btn { float: right; margin: 0 2em 1em 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="main-page">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id ="maindiv">



    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-right">Close</a>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" id="menu">

            <li>
            <a href="#" id = "btnservice" data-rel="close">Services<img id= "tmg" src="./images/iconb_service.png" class = "ui-li-thumb"/> 
            </a>
            </li>


        </ul>

    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnservice").on("click", function(){  

        $("#maindiv").empty();
        $("#maindiv").load("services.html");
    });

    </script>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: when I click on the li to load the page, I got the following msg: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/services.html. Orign null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.", source: file:///android_asset/index.html(0).
Thanks.

Comment: I googled the above message. People suggested to disable google chrome web security. Since I am using Linux, the command they suggest to run is "$ google-chrome --disable-web-security". However, I didn't find such google-chrome command and of course it returned me "Command not found." error when I tried under linux terminal.